# How to print CasperJS debugging results to text file

Tags: javascript, python, debugging, phantomjs, casperjs

I can't read the debugging issues in the command prompt. Can I send that to a text file in my PhantomJS or CasperJS scripts?

Here is my python code;

```py
import os
import subprocess

#proxies = {'https': 'http://wmhproxy2:8080'}
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

CASPER = "C:/casperjs/bin/casperjs"

#SCRIPT = os.path.join(APP_ROOT,'unicorn.js')
SCRIPT = os.path.join(APP_ROOT,'unicorn.js')

params = CASPER +' '+ SCRIPT
paper = subprocess.check_output(params,shell=True)
rock = paper.text
salesforce = open('S:/N/salesforce2.txt','w')
salesforce.write(write)
print(subprocess.check_output(params,shell=True))
```

CasperJS script:

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: "debug"
});

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.options.waitTimeout = 7000;

casper.start('http://www.click2houston.com/',function(){
  this.echo(this.getTitle());
}).viewport(1200,1000);

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can append the logs to a file in your CasperJS script.

CasperJS has an internal event management which exposes the [`log` event](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#log). A simple object is passed into the event handler which also contains the log message. If you want a different formatting of the logs, then you need to do it yourself or implement a [part of the log code](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/945171f7a380ea3365fd26e0103ba43b51bc40fc/modules/casper.js#L1337-L1347) in your event handler.

```js
var fs = require("fs");

fs.write("mylogfile.log", "", "w"); // overwrite log file
casper.on("log", function(entry){
    fs.write("mylogfile.log", entry.message + "\n", "a");
});
```

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS, so you can directly use [PhantomJS' file system module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/). Of course you can also pass the log file as a commandline option into the script and get it out through [`casper.cli`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/cli.html).

Comment: Please note that this is supposed to work from within a CasperJS script. CasperJS will write the mylogfile.log file into a directory from where the python script was started. As I said, if you want it in another location, you can pass an absolute log file path into the CasperJS script.

Comment: Hi Artjom do you know how I would add the proxy to the python section of the code? I am tried service agent, but i dont know where to inject it? i found documentation here about proxies. this is what i have so far.     `service_args = [
    '--proxy=wmhproxy2:8080',
    '--proxy-type=http'
    ]` above my APP_ROOT.